Huawei ME 936 4g/LTE issue
I have installed several flavors of Linux trying to resolve this Huawei ME 936 4g/LTE issue. The built-in modem manager discovers my 4g internet connection, I can connect to the provider and get a good signal, but when I open any websites it always comes back with no pages loading. I have tested the module on Windows 10 and it works flawless without an issue. I even double-checked that the APN settings are correct.
Here is a screenshot I took when trying out Zorin OS. Ubuntu, Mint  and Kubuntu were also  having the same issue.

Does anyone have any idea of what is currently going wrong with the WWAN module?

You've provided few specifics; you mention both on-topic & off-topic OSes but give no clues as to specifics. Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack choice, but we don't even know what product you tried, what release of that product, nor what kernel stack was tried; as drivers are actually kernel modules; thus changing kernel stack on the same release can be an easy fix!  If you want Linux support I'll suggest SE Unix & Linux, for Ubuntu support you'll need to provide specifics as to what you tried (I can download 5 ISOs with different kernels for just 22.04; but you've given no detail)


Do you have DHCP enabled (most often the easy way to get things working) or not.


how do i check the kernel version i just downloaded ubuntu off the website, the new one i usually try to keep around the ubuntu based OS "Download 24.04.1 LTS
5.8GB" i've essentially just flavour hopped linux trying to get it working but i usually have ubuntu

i did it, this actually fixed the issue on zorin, mint and ubuntu :)
$ sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/71-huawei-me936conf.rules
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", 
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", 
ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="15bb", 
ATTR{bNumConfigurations}=="3",
ATTR{bConfigurationValue}!="3" 
ATTR{bConfigurationValue}="3"
found it on another group. hope it helps anyone else having this issue not actually sure how it works, but it does now :D
